# Internet connectivity returns false for cellular networks on iphone(xamarin.ios)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin, internet-connection

The following code returns true for wifi connection but false while checking for cellular(wwan) network on device ,
here is the code

```cs
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
    request.Timeout = 25000;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    request.UseDefaultCredentials=true;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

i am getting the error as

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

help out.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you try to connect to a different site?  Could your carrier be using a proxy that is interfering with your connection?

Comment: You would **not** get a 403 error if the cellular networking did not work. That 403 comes from the server (so the request went thru). Something else (configuration, VPN, proxy...) is blocking you.

Comment: @Jason: ya its returning the same for all other sites.

Comment: @poupou:so how could we know that.what should we do to overcome that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Xamarin Reachability class [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/reachability/detect_if_network_is_available/).

Edit:

Download and install the vodafone profile from  http://db.tt/SqQGQ9Ci

Comment: Works fine on simulator...let me check on real device.

Comment: works on wifi network but doesnt work on cellular data.

Comment: If you are still getting 403 error then @poupou is true..activate your cellular data network..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reachibility

```
#import "Reachability.h"
+(bool)internetConnection
 {

Reachability* reachability;
reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
[reachability startNotifier];
switch (netStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        //[self showLoadingView:@"Internet Unavailable!!"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NetworkFail" object:self];
        return NO;
        break;
    }

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NEtworkPass" object:self];
        return YES;
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NEtworkPass" object:self];
        return YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i want it for Xamarin version.